# Field level audit on SQL Server using Trigger

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

I am trying to write a trigger which would audit a table's every field - a row's old value and new value in a table. If any of the field has been modified, I need to save the fields old value and the new value along with field name in an audit table, as a new entry.

```
create trigger Trg_Institution_FieldAudit on Table1 AFTER UPDATE AS
DECLARE @OldName VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @CurrentName VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @OldId VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @CurrentId VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @modifiedBy VARCHAR(30)
If update(Name)
  BEGIN
    select @OldName = Name from deleted
    select @CurrentName = Name from Inserted
    select @OldId = ID from deleted
    select @currentId = ID from Inserted
    select @modifiedBy = modifiedBy from deleted
    --INSERT statement for Name field alone
    END;
```

This works fine for a small number of fields, but I have a lot of fields (more than 60), and I am not achieving the performance that is required, because of a lot of if conditions. Is there a better way of doing this? On top of this, there are concurrent updates that are happening to around 3 million records in this table, which makes a lot of things go wrong :(

**EDIT: Only ONE row will get updated by an UPDATE statement**

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. WHich of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `select @OldName = Name from deleted` - it's non-deterministic - it'll pick one - and ignore all the other rows. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thank you. If we consider that the update statement always happen to one row at a time, i.e 1 UPDATE statement for 1 row, what would be the ideal way of checking all the columns that has been updated and make individual entries in the audit table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for an alternative for FOR EACH in SQL Server, I found that a CURSOR can be used. It serves the purpose, but need somebody to validate this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trg_Institution_FieldAudit_1 ON dbo.Institution FOR UPDATE as 

-- DECLARE Variables

DECLARE institution_cursor CURSOR DYNAMIC FOR SELECT * FROM DELETED
OPEN institution_cursor FETCH NEXT FROM institution_cursor INTO -- @variables here
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN    
        IF UPDATE(COL1)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO AuditTable VALUES (COL1, @prev, @next);
        END;

        FETCH NEXT FROM institution_cursor INTO -- @Variables here
    END
CLOSE institution_cursor
DEALLOCATE institution_cursor
```

Answer (score 2):

Oh my. Please avoid using a cursor whenever possible! You can easily use an insert statement with a select referencing the inserted and deleted tables. Below is a sample from one of my update triggers.

```
DECLARE @AuditTime DATETIME
SET @AuditTime = GetDate()

IF UPDATE([AccountManager])

    INSERT INTO Audit.AuditHistory (AuditId, AuditDate, AuditTableName,  EntityKey, AuditFieldName, OldValue, NewValue, FieldDisplayText, OldDisplayText, NewDisplayText, ModifiedBy)
    SELECT NewId(),
           @AuditTime,
           '[tblOpportunity]',
           cast(d.[GOTSID] AS varchar),
           '[AccountManager]',
           cast(d.[AccountManager] AS varchar(250)),
           cast(i.[AccountManager] AS varchar(250)),
           'Account Manager',
           isnull(cast(d.[AccountManager] AS varchar(250)), ''),
           isnull(cast(i.[AccountManager] AS varchar(250)), ''),
           isnull(i.[ModifiedBy], '')
    FROM deleted d
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON d.GOTSID = i.GOTSID 
    WHERE d.[AccountManager] <> i.[AccountManager]
    OR (d.[AccountManager] IS NOT NULL
        AND i.AccountManager IS NULL)
    OR (d.[AccountManager] IS NULL
        AND i.AccountManager IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

@marc_s is right, you have to re-construct your trigger and tables. here take example.

you need to put where condition in select @OldName = Name from deleted.

e.g.-

**

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trg_Institution_FieldAudit ON Table1 FOR UPDATE 
AS 
DECLARE @OldName VARCHAR(30) 
DECLARE @CurrentName VARCHAR(30)
IF UPDATE (Name) 
BEGIN
       SET @OldName = Table1.Name     FROM deleted
           WHERE Table1.Name = deleted.Name;        
   SET @CurrentName = Table1.Name     FROM inserted                    
           WHERE Table1.Name = inserted.Name ; 
 --INSERT statement for old and new values.         
END 
GO**
```

Comment: The op is using SQL Server, not Oracle (this is for Oracle, right?)

Comment: There seems to be no for each in sql server :(

Comment: Just curious to know how is this different from what I asked :(